# Why Thread.sleep() in a while (true)

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop

I am taking over a new project and I came across this bunch of code that just seems odd to me.  I am new to Java in general but I do have experience in C#.  What I understand from this is it will just keep trying to put a Thread to sleep?  It seems intentional to reduce performance or maybe I am totally off here.  Could anyone explain? Thank you.

```
while (true) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        break;
    }
    other stuff happening here;
}
```

Comment: Does it do anything after that? Maybe something that could be a problem if done without any pause between attempts?

Comment: No it's not for reducing performance, it's making a thread sleep a second at a time. If that' s the *only* thing the thread does, it's odd, but most likely it's just someone doing wait-polling because the author either didn't have better options (unlikely) or didn't know of any better options.

Comment: I think the "other stuff happening here" is probably the context that we would need to be able to make an educated guess.

Comment: That eternal loop might exist to make a server stay running, i.e. without it the server would terminate.

Comment: Re, "... intentional to reduce performance..." Nobody ever wants to reduce performance. Talk about "performance" is talk about how well the program satisfies its requirements. The sleep reduces the _rate_ at which the "other stuff" happens, but maybe the program would perform _poorly_ if the "other stuff" happened too often.

Comment: This is not uncommon.  I use such a sleep loop to flash a LED on embedded boards.  At a glance, without any further investigation, I can tell that the power is on, CPU hardware running and that, at least some of, the software is running.  The performance hit is negligible.  It needs, like, 16 words of stack and that's it:)

Answer (score 3):

## Take a break to let other threads execute

That code uses sleep merely to delay each repetition of the “other stuff” code. Without such a delay, the code may be running more often than is needed, wasting CPU cycles. While that thread is asleep, some  other thread can be running for that second.

This sleeping will be even more performant in the future if the [virtual threads](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/425) proposed by *Project Loom* succeed.

### `ScheduledExecutorSerivce`

An alternative approach is a [scheduled executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). A `Runnable` or `Callable` task could be [submitted to run with a second of pause time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) in between runs.

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;

Runnable task = () -> otherStuff() ;
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate ( task , 0 , 1 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ); // ( task , initialDelay , period , unit )

… // Eventually shutdown the executor service, otherwise the backing thread pool may run indefinitely.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not sufficient context to explain exactly the purpose of the `sleep` here.

One possibility is that this is simply to run the `other stuff happening here;` code roughly once a second ... because it needs to be run once a second.  This can be done other ways.

Another possibility is that it is a "hack" to avoid make a polling loop less "expensive".  For example compare these two bits of code:

```
volatile boolean someFlag;
...
while (true)
    if (someFlag) {
       //  do something
       someFlag = false;
    }
}
```

versus

```
volatile boolean someFlag;
...
while (true)
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        break;
    }
    if (someFlag) {
       //  do something
       someFlag = false;
    }
}
```

The idea of this code is to do something whenever some other thread sets `someFlag` is set to `true`.  The difference between the two versions is that the first one polls the flag at a high rate to achieve a quick response, while the second will not respond to the flag being set for up to a second.  On the other hand, the second version doesn't keep a core busy while waiting.

There are ways to get a fast response to the state change more efficiently; e.g. if the two threads use `wait` / `notify` or `Semaphores` or some other synchronization class.  Code that polls a flag with or without a `sleep` should be treated with suspicion ...